# err can't find IP when trying to update?

Tags: debian

The OS

```
 PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
        NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
        VERSION_ID="10"
        VERSION="10 (buster)"
        VERSION_CODENAME=buster
        ID=debian
```

this all started when I tried to install the default-jdk

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package default-jdk
```

when I tried to update I get this IP address error.

```
sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

is there something I can do to this to update and install the the java sdk? thanks.

Comment: WebUpd8 team's PPA is *dead* since April 2019. See https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java. It's better to remove that PPA.

Answer (score 0):

The `default-jdk`package is already available in Debian's official repositories: https://packages.debian.org/buster/default-jdk

You added PPAs that are for Ubuntu. `groovy` and `jammy` are names of Ubuntu releases. **NEVER do this**, don't mix Ubuntu repositories or PPAs in a Debian distro. Debian is NOT Ubuntu! [A FrankenDebian is always a bad idea.](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) Beside that, the specific PPAs added aren't updated since 2019, *de facto* "dead", and shouldn't be used even in Ubuntu.

So, the first step is to cleanup that mess. [Here's](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) a tutorial for editing and managing the software sources and [another](https://computingforgeeks.com/add-debian-10-buster-official-repositories-to-sources-list/) with the default Debian (Buster) repositories. Change yours accordingly by removing all those Ubuntu PPAs that shouldn't be there. Then you should be able to install this package.

Suggestion: Install Synaptic Package Manager and search for the packages you want to install from there.